# Mostrar input a partir de un select

Tags: html

Como puedo hacer que apartir de un select se me muestre un input determinado por ejemplo en el select tengo dos opciones Dui y pasaporte y al seleccionar uno de ellos que se me habilite un input diferente

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask], además, también puedes hacer el [tour] y conseguir tu primera medalla. En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿podrías subir el código de lo que has intentado? ¿Estás trabajando con alguna librería o framework? ¿Es solo HTML y Javascript puro? Si agregas un poco de detalle y contexto a tu pregunta, ésta será bien recibida y seguramente obtendrá respuestas. Saludos

Comment: Solo estoy con html y empiezo en javascript y lo unico que tengo solo es un select con tres opciones y al seleccionar uno de ellos quiero que se habilite un input determinado, si me ayudan muchas gracias

Comment: Cuando menos código tengas, mejor. Pero pon algo de código para que veamos en qué podemos ayudarte...